# Why do i have a null pointer exception on database calls and what can i do to solve?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, activeandroid

```
new AsyncTask<Ticket, Void, List<TPVLine>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<TPVLine> doInBackground(Ticket... params) {
            List<TPVLine> lines;
            while (true){
                Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for data base response");
                try {
                    lines = params[0].getLines();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Data base response completed");
                    break;
                }catch (SQLiteException | NullPointerException ex){
                    ActiveAndroid.clearCache();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cleaning cache");
                    Log.wtf(TAG, ex.toString());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            return lines;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<TPVLine> aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            linesTPV = new ArrayList<TPVLine>();
            if (aVoid != null){
                linesTPV = aVoid;
            }
            linesTPV.addAll(noSavedLines);
            mainActivity.getTpvFragment().resetPrice();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (linesTPV.size() == 0){
                mainActivity.getTpvFragment().getListContainer().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mainActivity.getTpvFragment().getMessageContainer().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                mainActivity.getTpvFragment().getListContainer().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mainActivity.getTpvFragment().getMessageContainer().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mainActivity.getCurrentTicket());
```

This are the calls, first in Ticket.java

```
public List<TPVLine> getLines() {
    return new Select().from(TPVLine.class).where("Ticket = ?", this.getId()).execute();
}
```

The second is in TPVLine.java

```
public static List<TPVLine> getLines(Ticket ticket){
    return new Select().from(TPVLine.class).where("Ticket = ?", ticket.getId()).orderBy("Id ASC").execute();
}
```

The issue is caused when i call TPVLine.class, i make sure first that Ticket != null. I'm using ActiveAndroid to manage the database

Comment: Did you read the fancy manual: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html? Because if I read correctly your code, `params[0]` is obviously `null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The problen ins't params[0], i pass a ticket and it is't null. The problem is a null pointer exception caused by call the method .getClass() on a null object, and i only use the .class or .getClass() in database calls

Comment: Maybe you should add a logstash output then

Answer (score 1):

you are returning `null` instead of `lines` in your asynctask `doInBackground` event.

```
return lines;
```

Comment: That would not cause an NPE with posted code, but that's a good catch

Comment: Thanks, i didn't watch this error. Any how, isn't the problem of NullPointer Exception because i check if the return is null before use them.

Comment: no you have to send return value in your case it is arraylist line so it will handle in onPostExecute.

Comment: and of course arraylist shouldn't be null either @KevinLopez

Comment: In onPostExecute i check first if the arraylist is != null before using it, and i don't use it if it is null

Comment: but you have to pass it instead of return null as I said in my answer. @KevinLopez

Comment: I know, i fix it yet